# How to force Angular2 to POST using x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a project that needs to use Angular2 (final) to post to an old, legacy Tomcat 7 server providing a somewhat REST-ish API using .jsp pages.

This worked fine when the project was just a simple JQuery app performing AJAX requests. However, the scope of the project has grown such that it will need to be rewritten using a more modern framework. Angular2 looks fantastic for the job, with one exception: It refuses to perform POST requests using anything option but as form-data, which the API doesn't extract. The API expects everything to be urlencoded, relying on Java's `request.getParameter("param")` syntax to extract individual fields.

This is a snipped from my user.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Response, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private loggedIn = false;
    private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/mpadmin/api/login.jsp';
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    login(username, password) {
        return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, {'username': username, 'password':  password}, this.headers)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let user = response.json();
                if (user) {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

No matter what I set the header content type to be, it always ends up arriving as non-encoded form-data. It's not honoring the header I'm setting.

Has anyone else encountered this? How do you go about forcing Angular2 to POST data in a format that can be read by an old Java API using `request.getParameter("param")`?

Comment: I think it's pretty lame that angular makes it so difficult to post as `www-form-urlencoded`. There should be first class support to do this easily.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore with Angular4+ and HttpClient.

Comment: You are correct, @stt106. This solution is old, and specific to earlier versions than 4. I will rewrite the solution above for HttpClient when I have time.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**UPDATE June 2020: This answer is 4 years old and no longer valid due to API changes in Angular. Please refer to more recent answers for the current version approach.**

---

You can do this using `URLSearchParams` as the body of the request and angular will automatically set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and encode the body properly.

```
let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', username);
body.set('password', password);

this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body).map(...);
```

The reason it's not currently working for you is you're not encoding the body data in the correct format and you're not setting the header options correctly.

You need to encode the body like this:

```
let body = `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
```

You need to set the header options like this:

```
this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers: headers }).map(...);
```

Comment: Tried the URLSearchParams() option, which didn't work, but you were absolutely right about the format of the body. That did the trick. Marked as the answer, and I'm going to update the post for other people to find.

Comment: I'm using `URLSearchParams` as the body for form data and having no problems.  I think it was introduced in RC4.  What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Final, but looking back, I'm pretty sure I just typo'd it, and since the second option worked, I didn't bother to retry. Thanks again for the assist, by the way.

Comment: @DamonKaswell No success using URLSearchParams as body, for me either. If I do that the content type is application/json and the json data posted is an empty object. I'm on Angular 4.0.  I ended up doing this `      const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
      const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      const body: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      body.set('username', username);
      body.set('password', password);

      return this.http.post(API_URL + 'login', body.toString(), options)`

Comment: If you're building the body string manually, remember to encode your username and password, otherwise certain characters won't be passed to the server correctly...

Comment: doing this same thing with httpClient instead in angular 8 works. But doing that in angular 5 does not (the content type does not set). Meanwhile, by angular 5, the Http module is deprecated. How can we do this in angular 5 ?

Comment: This solution is **deprecated**. See https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp. You can use [**`HttpParams`**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) now, like explained in [Robert Hegner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010503/9434800)

Comment: you should remember about `${encodeURIComponent(username)}, otherwise it can throw 400 Bad Request when username or password contains special characters!

Answer (score 127):

For Angular > 4.3 (New HTTPClient) use the following:

```
let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('user', username);
body.set('password', password);

let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};

this.http
    .post('//yourUrl.com/login', body.toString(), options)
    .subscribe(response => {
        //...
    });
```

Note 3 things to make it work as expected:

1. Use URLSearchParams for your body
2. Convert body to string
3. Set the header's content-type

**Attention**: Older browsers do need a polyfill! I used: `npm i url-search-params-polyfill --save` and then added to polyfills.ts: `import 'url-search-params-polyfill';`

Comment: Guys watch out you need a polyfill! I added it to the answer.

Comment: Ugh, angular. It's insane that we need to write such verbose boilerplate code to do such a simple thing.

Comment: Honestly i think that is pretty simple. What if you want to add more header options? Also the generation of x-www-form-urlencoded is automatically done by URLSearchParams. I dont see any boilerplate code at all here. If you do so, with the new beautiful Angular HttpClient you can create an [Interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#advanced-usage) and add your header options there. No duplicate code then. Ugh, Angular (is actually great!)

Comment: Shouldn't one use "new" Angular 5 `HttpParams` instead of "old" `URLSearchParams`?

Comment: Thanks, that was a puzzle!

Comment: HttpParams works and avoids the polyfill, but it is immutable, so you have to use body = body.set('user', username); etc.

Answer (score 41):

For those still looking for an answer this is how I solved it with Angular 5 and HttpClient:

```
const formData = new FormData();

// append your data
formData.append('myKey1', 'some value 1');
formData.append('myKey1', 'some value 2');
formData.append('myKey3', true);

this.httpClient.post('apiPath', formData);
```

Do **NOT** set Content-Type header, angular will fix this for you!

Comment: Nice! Thank you for an Angular 5 HttpClient solution. I've been migrating my project to Angular 5 and was looking into simplifying the posting process.

Comment: I need to include `Authorization` in the header, do I set it on the `formData` as well or set it in the `RequestOptions`?

Comment: how to append object in object? 
ex: option{
details: {
name : xx,
age : yy
}
}

Comment: @saghar.fadaei not sure but maybe this can help: https://gist.github.com/ghinda/8442a57f22099bdb2e34

Comment: This didn't work for me. It ended up sending the data as Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: @KaiG What did you try to send?

Comment: @JohanKvint - I tried to send a FormData. What worked for me was sending a UrlSearchParams and setting the Content-Type.

Comment: This does not actually send a url encoded body, but some sort of multipart body.

Comment: This request will generate header "multipart/form-data", It will not work if server accepts "x-www-form-urlencoded" only,

Answer (score 34):

This is what worked for me with Angular 7:

```
const payload = new HttpParams()
  .set('username', username)
  .set('password', password);

this.http.post(url, payload);
```

No need to explicitly set the header with this approach.

Note that the HttpParams object is immutable. So doing something like the following won't work, it will give you an empty body:

```
const payload = new HttpParams();
payload.set('username', username);
payload.set('password', password);

this.http.post(url, payload);
```

Comment: Am I missing something here, but this does not encode the parameters?

Comment: thanks man, after searching for 2 hours, this solution finally saved me. thanks my brother

Comment: @deanwilliammills yep, it skips encoding.

Comment: HttpParams are (now?) immutable. So you need to reassign the payload after every call on it.

Answer (score 6):

**Angular 9**

This is a code that works.

Take other options that fit to you to return not success answer.

```js
 let params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: { email: usuario.email, password: usuario.password, role: usuario.role },
    });

    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
    };
    
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/usuario/signup`, params.toString(), httpOptions).pipe(
      map(
        (resp) => {
        
          console.log('return http', resp);
          return resp;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('return http error', error);
          return error;
        }
      )
    );
```

remember from string you use `fromString` and not `fromObject`.

Answer (score 5):

I found out this solution after working several hours on this issue

```
login(userName: string, password: string) {
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append( 'No-Auth', 'True');

const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', userName);
body.set('password', password);
body.set('grant_type', 'password');

return this.http.post(
    this.baseUrl + '/token'
   , body.toString()
   , { headers: headers }
  )
  .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
  .pipe(map(res => {
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
    return true;
  }))
  .pipe(catchError((error: any) => {
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }));
```

}

Comment: helped me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: URLSearchParams class dont have a toString method

Answer (score 5):

When using angular forms most parameters will be sent as objects, hence your login function will most likely have this object
`form.value = {username: 'someone', password:'1234', grant_type: 'password'}` as the parameter

to send this object as **x-www-form-urlencoded** your code will be

```
export class AuthService {
    private headers = new HttpHeaders(
        {
            'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            Accept: '*/*',
        }
    );
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(data): Observable<any> {
    const body = new HttpParams({fromObject: data});
    const options = { headers: this.headers};
    return this.http.post(`${environment.baseUrl}/token`, body.toString(), options);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

For Angular 12, this is what worked for me.

```js
  options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  };

  params = new HttpParams()
  .set("client_id", "client_id")
  .set("client_secret", "client_secret")
  .set("grant_type", "grant_type")
  .set("scope", "scope")

  getToken(){
    return this._http.post(`${URL}`, this.params, this.options)
  }
```

Also, remember to import the following at the top `import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';`

Also notice that, unlike the others, we do not use toString() as it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I've been working on this since a while and thanks to this post from Josh Morony https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-an-ionic-application-with-a-nodejs-backend/ I figured out what the problem was. Basically, when I started testing my api I was using POSTMAN and it was working perfectly but when it came to implementing it with Ionic Angular it became a problem. The solution in this post is only about importing `body-parser` and use it as app middleware like this `app.use(bodyParser.json())` on your server-side root file(index).

Hopefully, this will help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Angular 8

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});
const params = new HttpParams();
params.set('username', 'username');
params.set('password', 'password');

this.http.post(
  'https://localhost:5000/api',
  params.toString(),
  { headers }
);
```

Comment: This does not work. HttpParams is immutable so using set like this won't work and give an empty body.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MaintenanceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //header de requete http
  private headers = new HttpHeaders(
    {  'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  );





// requete http pour recuperer le type des maintenances
 createMaintenance(data: createMaintenance){
  const options = { headers: this.headers};
   return this.http.post('api/v2/admin/maintenances', data, options ).subscribe(status=> console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};
let body = new URLSearchParams();

body.set('userId', userId);
body.set('discussionId', discussionId);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the following block of code:

```
const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', username);
body.set('password', password);

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .append(
         'Content-type',
         'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers }).map(...);
```