# New to Typescript & Angular problems with Http Post

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and Typescript and I try to create a simple login page. I've created a service in typescript which is invoked when the user presses the 'Login' button. The textboxes which contains the username and password is bound correctly to the model, but when I send the request to my backend written in C#, it will not hit the breakpoint which I suspect is because of the format of the message being sent on the wire.

So using `PostMan`, I'm able to invoke the service and get back an `access_token` When exporting the request to code in `PostMan` this is what the NodeJS variant look like:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8081/login',
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': '34dd4d0f-ff16-db4f-ebae-dab945729410',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  form: { username: 'test', password: 'test', grant_type: 'password' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

And this is my Typescript code

```
login(userName: string, password:string) : Observable<boolean> {

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

        var content = JSON.stringify({
            username: userName, 
            password: password,
            grant_type: this.grant_type
        });

        return this.http.post(this.authenticationEndpoint, content, {headers: headers})
                .map((response:Response) =>  {

                    let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                    if(token){
                        //this.token = token;
                        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({userName: userName, token:token}));
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                });        
    }
```

This results in an error in Visual Studio Code, which says:

[image]

I'm not really sure how I should interpret this error message, but since the method in my webservice is not invoked I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the HTTP headers or the format of the Http Post.. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing your are using Angular 4.3.4? Hard to tell. I think you don't have to JSON.stringify your content. Why are you using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' content type?

Comment: what is that postman token do you need to set it up ?

Comment: @ChrisY According to my package.json the @angular/core is set to ^4.2.4 which according to my understanding mean "all above this version"? Is there any other concrete way to check the version? Thanks!

Comment: @RahulSingh I guess I dont need it, probably something Postman adds automatically.

Comment: For content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' the request body should look like `parameter=value&also=another`

Comment: @ChrisY I see, so it's wrong to format it as Json..

Comment: You need to serialize it yourself to a string. using `URLSearchParams` .Tell me if you need an answer

Comment: guess so. you could try to use 'let content = `username=${userame}&password=${password}`; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `URLSearchParams` as the body of the request and angular will automatically set the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
import { URLSearchParams } from "@angular/http"

    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('username', username);
    body.set('password', password);
    .....


this.http.post(this.authenticationEndpoint, body).map(..)
```

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen as you are new a quick thought try and use the new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) instead of http its has been deprecated in Angular latest release

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! At least it breaks in my C# code, but when returned to typescript code, it give me this error: ERROR
Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
_body:ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, …}
headers:Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
ok:false
status:0
statusText:""
type:3
url:null
__proto__:Body {constructor: , toString: }