# Angular 2 HTTP post Web API 2 always receive null

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import * as myGlobal from '../global';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

postUser(user:any[]) {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-
  urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Accept' : 'application/json' });
  return this.http.post(myGlobal.myUrl + 'user/insert', JSON.stringify(user)
  , {headers: headers});
  }
}
```

**user.component.ts**

```
submitForm(data: any):void{
  console.log(data);
  this._service.postUser(data)
  .subscribe(
  (response) => console.log(response),
  (error) => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

**Web API**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/user/insert")]
public HttpResponseMessage insertVehiclesDevice(modelUser data)
{
  //stuff
  return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

When I invoke method Insert, the data always arrive in null or zero, 
I had to change the `{ 'Accept' : 'application/json' }` line for `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Accept' : 'application/json' }` because it gave me 405 error

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: I think this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782818/2708210 not so sure but might as the content type seems to be the problem i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
return this.http.post(myGlobal.myUrl + 'user/insert' 
     , JSON.stringify(user)
     , {headers: headers});
```

Change it to:

```
return this.http.post(myGlobal.myUrl + 'user/insert' 
     , JSON.stringify(user)
     , {headers: headers})
   .map(    (response: Response) =>response.json())
   .catch(this._errorHandler);
```

Error handler:

```
_errorHandler(error:Response){
  console.log(error);
  return Observable.throw(error || "Internal server error");
}
```

You will need some import:

```
  import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the code, but now all the data arrive null `firstName:null, country:0`. 
Also gives me the following error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Object.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: You gave your answer, means your JSON in not in correct format

Answer (score 0):

Change your input value to `user` , the passed `data's name` and the accepted parameter must be with same name. In `postUser` you get your data's name as `user`. Make the same in the `API` also.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/user/insert")]
public HttpResponseMessage insertVehiclesDevice(modelUser user)
{
  //stuff
  return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```