# Angular 6 HTTP Client Post - Bad request

Tags: angular

I have the following problem.
I have a server on which the API is, I send the request to the registration endpoint, but in response I get a 400 Bad Request error, stating that the name, surname, email etc must be filled out. The problem is that they are filled. I miss ideas anymore. My code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Brak tytułu';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    registerUser() {
        const config = {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')};
        const user: User = {
            name: 'Pawel',
            surname: 'Tester',
            email: 'tester@wp.pl',
            password: 'loremipsum12',
            password_confirm: 'loremipsum12',
            event_id: 1,
        };

        this.http.post('https://myapiserver', user, config).subscribe((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(user);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(user);
            });
    }
}

interface User {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    password_confirm: string;
    event_id: number;
}
```

This code works fine, but he is angularJS

```
    // User create
$scope.createUser = function()
{
    var create_req = $rootScope.reqDefaults;
        create_req.method = 'POST';
        create_req.url = $rootScope.api+'/admin/user';
        create_req.data = $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.current);
        create_req.transformRequest = angular.identity;

    // Users list
    $http(create_req)
        .then(function(response){
            $location.path('/users');
            $.notify({
                title: '<strong>Użytkownik utworzony.</strong>',
                message: $scope.current.name+' '+$scope.current.surname+' (ID: '+response.data.id+')'
            },{
                type: 'success'
            });
            return true;
        }, function(response){
            $rootScope.rspError(response.data);
            return false;
        });
};
```

If i send request to the register endpoint from Postman, all works fine, my user is register correctly :( I set content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Which web server you are using ?

Comment: hi, how is the server implemented? Using browser's Dev Tools you should be able to check the real content of the message. can you double check ?

Comment: I'm using the real API for Symfony 3, which is on the VPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HttpClient` from `Angular` is actually very smart in figuring out what type of content should your request have. By looking into the source code at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L293) line

```
if (this.body instanceof HttpParams) {
  return 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
}
```

you will see that it will set your required header for you if you set the body as `HttpParams`. So, the solution to your problem should be:

```
const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('name', 'foo')
  .set('surname', 'bar')

this.http.post('https://myapiserver', body).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the content headers, which will set them to JSON by default , or set them for JSON like that: `application/json`

If your API however expects form encoded payload, then you should leave the header just like you have it, but modify the request to send form encoded data like this:

```
  const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('name', 'Pawel')
    .set('surname', 'Tester');

  this.http.post('https://myapiserver',
    body.toString(),
    config
  );
```

Comment: I set the first time on application / json, the second time I did not set at all, unfortunately I still have a bad request.

Comment: Does your API expect JSON body ? if not, please see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
const config = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                .set('Accept', 'application/json')

this.http.post('https://myapiserver', JSON.stringify(user), 
               { headers: config }).subscrib.....
```

Hope this helps

EDIT : using new HttpClientModule

```
const formData = new FormData();

// append your data
formData.append('myKey1', 'some value 1');
formData.append('myKey1', 'some value 2');
formData.append('myKey3', true);

this.httpClient.post('https://myapiserver', formData);
```

Do NOT set Content-Type header, angular will fix this for you!
source : [How to force Angular2 to POST using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded/45962083)

Comment: I use a asp.net core webapi that accepts JSON, don't know if that is your case

Comment: Bad request :( See my question

Comment: Thats why I added JSON.stringify(user), but that will work if your endpoint accepts JSON.  I saw a example of Symfony (https://andrewadcock.com/a-simple-restful-api-tutorial-with-symfony-3/) that expects the params in the url. I don't know what is your case. Try first with postman to see what works.

Comment: I add endpoint to postman, set content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, send request. Status code 200, my user register correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems I see here:
the HttpHeaders is missing the Authorization:

```
const config = {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
HttpHeaders().set('Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials);
HttpHeaders().set('Accept':'*/*')
};
```

where credentials can be: `const credentials = btoa("angularUser"+":"+"password");` must be defined in te CORS of the backend to be validated.

Another thing is the body, should be defined as follows:

```
let user = new URLSearchParams();

user.set('param1', 'value1');
user.set('param2', 'value2');
```

...

And if is not working, try to change the `Content-type from 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to `'application/json'`.
This worked form me at least.