# Angular login withCredentials:true doesnt work

Tags: angular, http, spring-lemon

Logging in using restAPIfails in browser , but works in postman.

here is my angular code for login, which throws me 401

```
    login(username: string, password: string) {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
                     .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                     .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + '/api/core/login',
     JSON.stringify({ 'username': username, 'password': password }), {withCredentials: true, headers: httpHeaders})
        .pipe(map(response => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            const token = response.headers.get('Lemon-Authorization');
            if (response.status === 200 && token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('authHeader', 'Bearer ' + token);
                this.currentUserSubject.next(response.body.user);
            }

            return response.body.user;
        }));
}
```

401 in chrome:
[faliure in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq4XT.png)

200 OK in postman :
[success in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t1UX.png)

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason could be that you are JSON stingifying the request body, whereas it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, i.e. `username=abc&password=xyz`. You could look at working Spring Lemon demo code for such issues, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/lemon-demo-angularjs/app/scripts/controllers/login.js#L23).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are facing a known `CORS` problem. The reason it works on postman is because It doesn’t do the called `preflight` request that the browsers do when you send authentication headers.

You will probably see in your requests in the browser that the failed request is an `OPTIONS` and not a ‘POST’. If that’s the case it means your server configuration is lacking `CORS` configurations.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i had cors cofigurationofmy server correct, i only messed up to specify Angular to POST using x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 1):

here is working code :

```
 login(username: string, password: string) {
            const body = new URLSearchParams();
            body.set('username', username);
            body.set('password', password);
            const options = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders()
                    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
                withCredentials: true
            };
            return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + '/api/core/login',
                body.toString(), options)
                .pipe(map(response => {
                    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                    const token = response.headers.get('Lemon-Authorization');
                    if (response.status === 200 && token) {
                        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                        localStorage.setItem('authHeader', 'Bearer ' + token);
                        this.currentUserSubject.next(response.body.user);
                    }

                    return response.body.user;
                }));
        }
```

more info here - 
[How to force Angular2 to POST using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded)