# ANGULAR : POST request return null

Tags: angular

when i add a new group i want to have an answer like the one on postman because i need the object id add

[image]

this is my function in service

```
addGroupe(groupe: Groupe): Observable<Groupe> {
    return this.http
      .post<Groupe>(`${this.url}/groupe`, groupe)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('addGroupe', groupe)))
  }
```

and here is the function to retrieve the answer, but it always returns null

```
this.groupeService.addGroupe(groupe).subscribe((resp: Groupe) => {
      console.log("response", resp);      
    });
```

[image]

Comment: In your Postman example, you are executing a POST of type content-type `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but in your HttpClient post(), you are not specifying that content-type, so by default Angular will send it as a content-type `application/json`. Is your API accepting the POST from Angular and doing what you expect?

Comment: First try updating the post() to send data as type `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded. Basically try using [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change :

```
addGroupe(groupe: Groupe): Observable<Groupe> {
    return this.http
      .post<Groupe>(`${this.url}/groupe`, groupe)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('addGroupe', groupe)))
}
```

To :

```
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};
addGroupe(groupe: Groupe): Observable<Groupe> {
    return this.http
      .post<Groupe>(`${this.url}/groupe`, groupe, options)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('addGroupe', groupe)))
}
```

**Additional:**
to make sure all browsers support it I recommend using polyfill

> `import 'url-search-params-polyfill';`
>
> `npm i url-search-params-polyfill --save`

**More explicitly** :
CORS errors can happen for several reasons but always about security risk, the server have the right to determine the access the client has, and the browsers followers its instructions that are a part of the `response headers`, like:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'application/json'
```

You issue if more likely as I suggested earlier (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). However in the off chance that didn't work you can run `curl -I http://ip:port` in terminal (or cmd but need to be installed if you're using windows) to see if the server `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is allowing your client. Either by specifying the IP:PORT or `*`(means that all are allowed). If you're not allowed then you can either change the response headers in the server (if you can access to) or use a `CORS proxy` (if the server is on the WAN not just locally stated), or use a browser plugin to ignore the server instructions but I wouldn't recommend that because other users would be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting cors origin error, means you angular application on `localhost:4200` and your api on `localhost:8000`
if you are using dotnet core as your backend you can set your cors settings 
 [dotnet core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Or you can use cors from google store 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the return of null of a http post request, is the invalid response code such as 205 : Reset Content,
the server must return a valid http response code (200:OK)
See this link to capture HTTP Response code
[Angular : Handling HTTP Response](https://angular.io/guide/http)