# How to send data to api

Tags: javascript

I am trying to integrate payment gateway to my application. Their docs (https://razorpay.com/docs/route/api-reference/#funds-movement-in-linked-accounts) say I have to send request like this:

```
   curl https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_AlSXPEsTyXyxYx/transfers \
   -u <YOUR_API_KEY>:<YOUR_SECRET_KEY> \
   -d 'transfers[0][account]=acc_BYYYYJRfs1234S' \
   -d 'transfers[0][amount]=1000' \
   -d 'transfers[0][currency]=INR' \
   -d 'transfers[0][notes][roll_no]=IEC2011025' \
   -d 'transfers[0][notes][name]=Gaurav Kumar' \
   -d 'transfers[0][linked_account_notes][0]=roll_no' \
   -d 'transfers[1][account]=acc_BYYYYJRfs1234S' \
   -d 'transfers[1][amount]=1000' \
   -d 'transfers[1][currency]=INR' \
   -d 'transfers[1][notes][roll_no]=IEC2011026' \
   -d 'transfers[1][notes][name]=Saurav Kumar'
```

I send the data as an object and doing `angular.toJson()` on it. I get 400 bad request

```
   let payData =
  {
    account: 'anccount',
    rzp_test_abcd:  'tyaef', //key
    amount: parseInt($scope.amountPayingNow*100),

  }
```

Calling their API:

```
 $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/'+ transaction.razorpay_payment_id + '/transfers',
    data: angular.toJson(payData),
  });
```

Comment: Giving the keys to your account to everybody who visits your site seems like a pretty huge security problem.

Comment: @Quentin do you mean the `account: 'anccount',`?

Comment: No, `-u <YOUR_API_KEY>:<YOUR_SECRET_KEY> \` (which you haven't included in your JS but which is going to be needed to access the API). It's secret for a reason.

Comment: @Quentin what do i do then? save it back end and get it?

Comment: @Quentin how do i send the key?

Comment: Contact api.razorpay.com from your backend after you have approved the request from the client.

Comment: @Quentin i dont get it.. what do you mean by "approved the request from the client"

Comment: Presumably you want to put some conditions in place before you transfer money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the curl manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

> -d/--data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F/--form.

Now see your code:

> ```
> data: angular.toJson(payData),
> ```

JSON is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded!

You need to encode the data in the expected format.

Now see [How to force Angular2 to POST using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded) elsewhere on Stackoverflow for an implementation of the solution.