# How to send postman-like, application/x-www-form-urlencoded post request in angular

Tags: angular, postman, angular-httpclient

I write an angular based client app for Django API project. One of the endpoints accepts application/x-www-form-urlencoded formatted requests, as it contains both file and string data and I'm pretty sure it works just fine on server-side - I've prepared an application/x-www-form-urlencoded request using POSTMAN:

```
HEADERS:
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
BODY (form-data):
   experiment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/experiments/6/
   measurement: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/measurements/4/
   variable: 
   x_axis: X_AXIS
   y_axis: Y_AXIS
   file_object: // here I've changed the field type and chose the .txt file
```

Of course the server responded correctly, and file has been added. Here's how the exact request's body looks like:

```
experiment=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/experiments/6/measurement=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/measurements/4/variable=x_axis=os Xy_axis=os Yfile_obj=[object Object]
```

But now, things are getting more complicated. I try to prepare the same request in Angular using reactive form and HttpClient. Let's say the reactive form itself works as should, but sending the request with 'Content-Type' set to:

- 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' returns '500 Internal Server Error', and
- 'multipart/data-form' return '415 Unsupported Media Type'

Here's how I send the request:

```
post(formGroup: FormGroup): Observable<DataFile> {
    const httpOption = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };

    return this.httpClient.post<DataFile>(this.apiEndpoints.datafilesCreateEndpoint(), formGroup.value, httpOption);
  }
```

and here's how the exact request looks like:

```
{"experiment":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/experiments/6/","measurement":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/measurements/4/","variable":" ","x_axis":"X AXIS","y_axis":"Y AXIS","file_obj":"C:\\fakepath\\navon.txt"}
```

Dunno why the request's Form Data is a JSON when I have set the Content-Type to a different one. Could it be a reason of this problem?

@UPDATE Solution

I've removed the httpOptions from post function, to let the Angular pass the Content-Type automatically. Then, instead of passing the FormGroup.value to httpClient's post, I've created the FormData and passed it instead.

Here's how my POST function looks like:

```
post(experiment: SharedModel, measurement: SharedModel, andOtherDataINeed: any): Observable<DataFile> {

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('experiment', experiment as any);
    ...
    fd.append('file_obj', file);

    return this.httpClient.post<DataFile>(this.apiEndpoints.datafilesCreateEndpoint(), fd);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded/39864307#39864307

Comment: @FrancescoFortin It's a step forward, indeed and thank you for this answer, but the form's file input tag returns the "fake" file path instead of File object as I expected - need to find out how to handle this.

Comment: Transform that file to base64 encoded and post that base64 instead.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `FormData` gets sent as `multipart/form-data`. If you want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, use `new HttpParams({ fromObject: formGroup.value })`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to research Axios library https://github.com/axios/axios

If you scroll down, you will notice example that sou need. You can use Axios in Angular app without problems.

Comment: I've tried this, but found a simpler solution. Thank you.

Comment: Can you write your solution so people who get here can see it.

Comment: I've added the solution in main post

Answer (score -1):

Change your original code to

```js
    return this.httpClient.post<DataFile>(this.apiEndpoints.datafilesCreateEndpoint(), new HttpParams({ fromObject: formGroup.value }));
```

`FormData` gets sent as `multipart/form-data`, not as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.