# Angular 8 - Post params sending in incorrect format

Tags: angular

I want to send post params to a endpoint, this m      const httpOptions = {

```
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    })
  };
  return this.http.post('http://localhost/post.php', {
    "name":  "Customer004",
    "email":  "customer004@email.com",
    "tel":  "0000252525"
    }, httpOptions);
}
```

In localhost/post.php i got the follow code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

The problem is that the navigator is sending the data in incorrect format. The browser send the follow:
[in incorrect format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASGXR.png)
instead:
[in correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NziX5.png)

The response of the php code is:

```
Array ( [{"name":"Customer004","email":"customer004@email_com","tel":"0000252525"}] => )
```

instead:

```
Array ( ["name"]=>"Customer004",["email"]=>"customer004@email_com",["tel"]=>"0000252525" )
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Remove the quotes from the keys of the JSON object you're sending over. Looks like you're sending over a JSON object instead of a Javascript Object, if that's your plan. See. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975890/697079

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall i put the code like that:
 name:  "Customer004",
 email:  "customer004@email.com",
 tel:  "0000252525"
and the problem persist

Comment: Maybe change the headers to `'Content-Type':  'application/json',`

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall that returns 'Array ( )' by the PHP code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Angular2 to POST using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the heading `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` it dictates how the angular service `http` will format the data sent to the backend.

Change it to `application/json` and you will get your expected format

```
headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
})
```

looking at a [php example](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/), it might be that you need to change your php code to decode json... but that's not my expertise.

I can try to guess based on the example that it would be something like this:

try:

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST));
```

Comment: When i use:
`'Content-Type': 'application/json'` the PHP code returns `Array ( )`

Comment: that's a server side issue... with `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` angular will send `{"name":  "Customer004", "email":  "customer004@email.com", "tel":  "0000252525" }` you can verify it on your browser`s development tools network tab

Comment: Yes, it send: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASGXR.png
But i need to that send: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NziX5.png (in that way is that the browser send when i use a traditional form)

Comment: that's incorrect... this form(formulario) payload tool from your pic is showing an attempt to parse the payload as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I updated the answer with a possible suggestion for you

Comment: The solution (a new code that you post) dont work, that returns a blank page (null).
But why dont work in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mode like the browser send in a traditional form?

Comment: the question was about angular though.... you are also having trouble with php  (as i said not my expertise).

Comment: as you are having trouble parsing the json payload in php. you can use ` URLSearchParams()` as the answer to this question presents:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864307/4604645

Comment: The problem is not PHP, becasue when i send the form with a traditional HTML form, that works fine and PHP code return the variables correctly.

Comment: I encourage you to study how to parse json payloads in PHP. Angular can send `x-www-form-urlencoded` payloads, but that's kind of hacky as you can see on this answer link i sent you.