# POST request success on POSTMAN but not on Angular 7

Tags: php, angular, api

I have followed this link: [Postman 'POST' request sucess but Angular 5 'Post' not working](http://microsoft.aspnet.webapi.cors), and have followed it to rectify my problem but some how it is not getting resolved. It always gives me `else block` output which I will show you in the Angular code itself.

**Note:** Working perfectly for POSTMAN.

**Possible Error:** There is a problem in my PHP code which is not been able to identify the input.

My API is a POST API, which accepts one param that is `phone_num`, which is mandatory. Passing the param from Postman works for the api, but when I do it by Angular, it doesn't work and goes to the `else block` of the API code.

Since this is a **RAW PHP Code**, so I don't know how to import this **the microsoft.aspnet.webapi.cors package** into my RAW PHP file, or will it fix this issue or not.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    include('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php');
    $request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    if ( $request_method == 'POST' ){
            if(isset($_GET['phone_num'])){
               echo $_GET['phone_num'];
            }else{
              echo 'No phone number found';
            }
    }else {
        echo 'No defined function for this method. Please use POST only';
    }
?>
```

For POSTMAN, I get the `phone_num` showing up in the console/body. But for Angular, the console shows: `No phone number found` which is weird.

**Angular Code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export class AppComponent {
  message: string;
  url: string = 'xxxxxxx';
  customernum: number;
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  callMe(){
    this.message = 'Please wait....'
    this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify({ 'phone_num': this.customernum }), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

I have also checked that `this.customernum` is printing the number correctly in the console, it is being passed in the console, checked in the `Network Console` of `Chrome Dev`.

**Error Log in Console:**

[image: Error log message]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Don't stringify it, just send simple object.

Comment: You do not need to use JSON.stringify. It is the default behavior.

Comment: Can you add html snippet, how you input customernum?

Comment: I will show you here @AayushiDassani `<input type="text" name='phoneForm' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="customernum" placeholder="Please put in your number so that we can call you">`

Comment: Doesn't help @Mridul, there is some problem with the data being send to the api, which always throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I personally would like to thank two people for this, they are:
>
> - [Nijeesh Joshy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6904782/nijeesh-joshy) for sorting the biggest problem METHOD to METHOD contradiction with PHP script.
> - [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5782634/brad) for explaining the correct formatting for smooth functioning of the operation

**Findings:** For making this work like normal, that is `$_POST` working POST methods, **you need to send the application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type in your header**. I don't know but sending out the data in Content-Type `application/json` just won't work.

**Solutions:**

**1. SyntaxError: Unexpected token N =>** This was done because in the PHP script, it has to be returned in `json_encode()`, that is why it was returning this error in this statement `No phone number found, N at 0th position` in the else script.

```
<?php
    include('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php');
    $request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    if ( $request_method == 'POST' ){
            if(isset($_POST['phone_num'])){
               echo $_POST['phone_num'];
            }else{
              echo json_encode('No phone number found');
            }
    }else {
        echo json_encode('No defined function for this method. Please use POST only');
    }
?>
```

**2. $_POST not working for POST method from Angular code =>** Explained already FINDINGS above.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export class AppComponent {
  message: string;
  url: string = 'xxxxxxx';
  customernum: number;
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
  };

  body: any = `phone_num=${this.customernum}`;  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  callMe(){
    this.message = 'Please wait....'
    this.http.post(this.url, this.body, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

If you're still getting error, then would be some formatting errors in your angular code. Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864307/5362583) link. I hope that'd help you anyway. I saw people were very strict on using `$_POST[] in place of $_GET[]`, but `Content-Type` was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

you are using $_GET to retrieve your "POST" data

try `$_POST['phone_num']` insted of `$_GET['phone_num']`

Comment: I am getting the same error, it is going on the else block everyt ime. Code was `if(isset($_POST['phone_num'])){ echo $_POST['phone_num'] }else { echo 'No number found'}`

Comment: then debug in code try: `print_r($request_method); exit;` and check why it is going on else block. I hope it will help

Comment: It's obviously `POST` in the console. I have checked it. My code is kinda correct, it is just that the information is not being taken from the Angular correctly, since **POSTMAN** implements the api right, and it works on it. Doing my code takes me into the `if block`, but using `$_POST` always pushes me to `else block`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the raw object `{ 'phone_num': this.customernum }`, don't use `JSON.stringify()`

Try like this:

```
callMe(){
    this.message = 'Please wait....'
    this.http.post(this.url, { 'phone_num': this.customernum }, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

Comment: No difference Adrita, same error. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form than try to add value from that form directly instead of any extra variable.  Replace form here by your form name

```
this.http.post(this.url, { 'phone_num': this.form.value.phoneForm}, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
```

Comment: `this.form.value.phoneForm` doesn't work in angular, we use `[(ngModel)]` and the data is definitely coming fine on the console.

Comment: If having form than can use either form or model, totally dependant on requirement. Try to use JSON.parse() instead of stringify.Here it is something related to data format

Answer (score 0):

SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON means you've got some malformed JSON, which is usually a string in there that's not wrapped in quotes.
1) Check if this.customernum is not empty or does not consist of any bad character.
2) Enclose phone_num in double-quotes.

Comment: I have checked for both the points, **Not Empty, doesn't contain bad character, it is a string containing number**. Secondly, **putting phone number in double quotes doesn't help**. I have also tried this, `{ "phone_num": "xxxxxxxx"}`, doesn't help

Comment: Just add the key phone number in double quotes and not the value

Comment: Not helping Error-404. Same error. The data is going null there, I don't know why

Answer (score -1):

you are getting `phone-number` from `$_GET`, so you should pass `phone_num` as [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

like this:

```
http://example.com/blablabla?phone_num=0123456789
```

Postman will do this automatically for you in `GET` requests