# bad request when connecting paypal account to get acess token

Tags: angular, http, paypal, postman

As mentionned in the official documentation [extract access token](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#6-get-access-token)

I want to integrate a paypal sandbox account into my Angular application 
but I have encoutered
**" 400 bad request error "** 
when I send a rest call to  get access token

```
 connectToPaypalAccount(paypalCode) : Observable<any> {

const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization' , 'Basic '+this.paypalClientID+':'+this.paypalClientSecret);

  const body = {
  grant_type : 'authorization_code' ,
  code: paypalCode
  }
   return this.http.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' , body , { headers }); }
```

i m sure that i have a valid ( clientID , Secret , authorization code ) and it works with postman  
see this picture below
[image]

any help is appreciated

Comment: Try: `set('Authorization' , 'Basic ' + btoa(this.paypalClientID + ':' + this.paypalClientSecret))`?

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work you may need FormData for your body, rather than json: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560146/7733570

Comment: i found the solution it s just an invalid body type 
i must send a **string** type instead of **json** or **formData** 
`const body ='grant_type=authorization_code&code='+paypalCode;`