# Can't make a x-www-form-urlencoded POST in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, post, angular-httpclient, angular12

I have a working POST and GET service and see no issues with CORS or such. However, I simply fail to mimic the call performed in Postman (where it works) and the only thing I can imagine is that I somehow set the *x-www-form-urlencoded* format incorrectly. Googling for examples gave me a **lot** of Spanish and Chinese sites for some reason. Copying examples from there, didn't resolve anything, though.

```
getToken(code: string): Observable<any> {

  let url = "https://localhost:44301/connect/token";

  let payload = {
    client_id: "awesome_client",
    client_secret: "HakunaMatata",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:44304/page01",
    code: code,
    grant_type: "authorization_code"
  };

  let headers = { "Content-Type": "x-www-form-urlencoded" };
  let options = { headers: headers };
  
  return this.http.post<any>(url, payload, options);
}
```

I understand there's some [changes in Angular 12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864307/1525840) so I tried a different version (also based on googling and examples). Same problem.

```
getToken(code: string): Observable<any> {
  ...
  return this.http.post<any>(
    url,
    payload.toString(),
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    });
}
```

I simply fail to see what I'm missing. Postman produces expected result (*body/x-www* enabled).

> https://localhost:44301/connect/token
> client_id:awesome_client
> client_secret:HakunaMatata
> redirect_uri:http://localhost:44304/page01
> code:4B822...
> grant_type:authorization_code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an objet as body of the HTTP Client, it will serialize it to json.
If you want to send your data as x-www-form-urlencoded you need to use an [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) as body.

```js
  getToken(code: string) {
    let url = 'https://localhost:44301/connect/token';

    let param = {
      client_id: 'awesome_client',
      client_secret: 'HakunaMatata',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:44304/page01',
      code: code,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    };
    var payload = new HttpParams({ fromObject: param });

    let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded' };
    let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.post<any>(url, payload, options);
  }
```